# jLabel won't print from String

Tags: java, string, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to populate a jLabel with text from a global String in NetBeans, but every time I try to print anything other than a String literal, it prints nothing. I've tried directly printing the String, and my most recent attempt used a get() method.

Here's the code so far, I'm populating the label on line 73:

```
    public class ChatWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Integer userID;
    private String otherPerson = "";

    /**
     * Creates new form ChatWindow
     * @param id
     */
    public ChatWindow(int id) {
        initComponents();
        userID = id;
        otherPerson = userID.toString();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        otherPersonLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        openMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        saveMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        saveAsMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        exitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        editMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        cutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        copyMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        pasteMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        deleteMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        helpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        contentsMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        aboutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(248, 248, 248));
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.setText("ContactName: FloopyNoops\nYou: Yes, floopynoops");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton1.setText("Send");

        jButton2.setText("Save");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        otherPersonLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        otherPersonLabel.setText(getLabelText());

        fileMenu.setMnemonic('f');
        fileMenu.setText("File");

        openMenuItem.setMnemonic('o');
        openMenuItem.setText("Open");
        fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);

        saveMenuItem.setMnemonic('s');
        saveMenuItem.setText("Save");
        fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);

        saveAsMenuItem.setMnemonic('a');
        saveAsMenuItem.setText("Save As ...");
        saveAsMenuItem.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(5);
        fileMenu.add(saveAsMenuItem);

        exitMenuItem.setMnemonic('x');
        exitMenuItem.setText("Exit");
        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                exitMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        editMenu.setMnemonic('e');
        editMenu.setText("Edit");

        cutMenuItem.setMnemonic('t');
        cutMenuItem.setText("Cut");
        editMenu.add(cutMenuItem);

        copyMenuItem.setMnemonic('y');
        copyMenuItem.setText("Copy");
        editMenu.add(copyMenuItem);

        pasteMenuItem.setMnemonic('p');
        pasteMenuItem.setText("Paste");
        editMenu.add(pasteMenuItem);

        deleteMenuItem.setMnemonic('d');
        deleteMenuItem.setText("Delete");
        editMenu.add(deleteMenuItem);

        menuBar.add(editMenu);

        helpMenu.setMnemonic('h');
        helpMenu.setText("Help");

        contentsMenuItem.setMnemonic('c');
        contentsMenuItem.setText("Contents");
        helpMenu.add(contentsMenuItem);

        aboutMenuItem.setMnemonic('a');
        aboutMenuItem.setText("About");
        helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);

        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(otherPersonLabel)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(otherPersonLabel)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 202, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void exitMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        this.dispose();
    }                                            

    private String getLabelText(){
        return otherPerson;
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem aboutMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem contentsMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem copyMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem cutMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem deleteMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JMenu editMenu;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem exitMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu;
    private javax.swing.JMenu helpMenu;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem openMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JLabel otherPersonLabel;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem pasteMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem saveAsMenuItem;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem saveMenuItem;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of unrelated code for you to expect a volunteer to wade through. For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the constructor is your issue.

```
public ChatWindow(int id) {
    initComponents(); //otherPerson = "";
    userID = id;
    otherPerson = userID.toString(); //otherPerson = id;
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

You initialize the component before otherPerson is set. Move `initComponents` after setting otherPerson and it should work again.

Comment: He actually never instantiates ChatWindow. The order doesn't matter if you never create the object where otherPerson is set.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Definitely flew right past me.

Comment: @MarsAtomic He could instantiate this from a HomeWindow or from a main method in another class.

Comment: For some reason, I thought ChatWindow was an inner class. Edited post? Insufficient caffeine? We'll never know...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling "initcomponent" first and then initializing "otherPerson" class member. Do it like this:

```
public ChatWindow(int id)
{
    userID = id;
    otherPerson = userID.toString();

    initComponents();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```